Lambdas and method reference use different approaches to non-final variables. Why?
I don't get this one.
In a lambda expression, you simply cannot reference non-final variables.
// doesn't compile
    @Test
    void methodReferenceTest() {
        String message = "123";
        message = "1234";
        Supplier<Integer> messageLengthSupplier = () -> message.length();
        System.out.print("Message length: ");
        message = "12345";
        System.out.print(messageLengthSupplier.get());
    }

But in a method reference, you can do that, but any reassignments after the method reference will be ignored.
    @Test
    void methodReferenceTest() {
        String message = "123";
        message = "1234";
        Supplier<Integer> messageLengthSupplier = message::length;
        System.out.print("Message length: ");
        message = "12345";
        System.out.print(messageLengthSupplier.get()); // prints 4
    }

Why didn't Java creators use one approach for both lambdas and method references?
There are questions relating to Java creators' design decisions (example), so I believe this question is as good (and as on-topic) as the others.
I'm not satisfied by "because method references are like method handles" (so I don't expect it to be marked as the question's duplicate). Well, why do they act like method handles? That just rephrases the problem instead of answering the question.

Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585 and clarify what kind of answer are you expecting. The sentence "Well, why do they act like method handles?" makes me think that you are just going to keep asking "why" ad infinitum. Also note that using a 10-year-old question to justify the validity of your question is generally (I am not saying anything about this specific case) not a good argument - Stack Overflow has changed a lot since then.

Because they’re two very different things.  One is a deferred expression, the other uses the method of an object obtained from a variable (not the variable itself).

@VGR you just rephrased the problem, it's not an answer

You asked “why are these things not the same” and the answer is, “because they’re not the same.”  They are different things with different behaviors.  You are seeing some similarities and assuming the two are the same concept, when they are not.

@VGR but they could be. Why couldn't method references be just syntactic sugar for lambdas when you don't need to pass explicit args? Why did Java creators decide to make method references behave so unlike lambdas (I could also mention Objects.requireNonNull() that javac inserts before non-static non-this method references)?

"Why did Java decide to do it this way" is generally considered off topic for StackOverflow.

When you do message::length you are taking the value of the message variable (which is a string), and then saying “I want the length method of this string”. That’s why subsequent assignments to message have no effect on the method — the method reference is still referring to the original string object!
By contrast, when you use a lambda expression, you are, at least conceptually, capturing the message variable itself — its value would not be checked until you actually call the anonymous function. This potentially creates some tricky situations, for example if the anonymous function outlives the scope in which it was created. Some languages, like most Lisp dialects and Python, allow this. Java cops out by forcing the variable to be “effectively final”. See also Wikipedia on the “funarg problem”.
Edit/Addendum I think it boils down to what expectations programmers coming from other languages might have on the different constructs. For message::length, I doubt anyone would expect that the method reference would be tied to the variable and not to its value. I am not aware of any language with a similar feature that does it that way. For example, Python does the same as Java here. In a lambda, on the other hand, it is not as clear-cut what is “right”. Does the value get copied, like in an Objective-C block (unless it’s declared __block)? Does it refer to the same variable, including subsequent changes to it? That’s the way Python and Lisp do it, and it’s very powerful, but comes with implementation headaches. The Java designers chose to circumvent the problem by forcing the variable to be read-only, thus making it irrelevant when its value is taken.

This is also why there is a difference between System.out::println and s -> System.out.println(s). While they appear to be the same the two behave differently if System.setOut is called after the method reference / lambda is created.

Again, you just rephrased the problem
